# Forwarding The Same Port To Multiple LAN Servers?

Tags: router, port, port-forwarding, wake-on-lan

I would like to be able to use the Wake-On-LAN feature to be able to turn on the two computers attached to my router when i am out of the house using my WAN IP Address.

Router = 81.210.109.0
PC A = 192.168.0.2
PC B = 192.168.0.3

Now i have set port forwarding up on my router which takes incoming connections of UDP port 9 and then forwards the packet to LAN server 192.168.0.2

How would i go about choosing which LAN computer i would wake when my router only allows my to forward a port to a single computer, Or is this even possible?

Thanks for any input on the matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. (At least, not in the way to asked.)

You need an unique combination of IP and port number to determine what to do with it. In your case you want:

- External IP 81.210.109.0, port 9, forwarded to 192.168.0.2, port 9
- External IP 81.210.109.0, port 9, forwarded to 192.168.0.3, port 9

There is no way your router will known which of those two rules to use.

What you can do is is to forward a port to another port number. For instance:

- External IP 81.210.109.0, port 9, forwarded to 192.168.0.2, port 9
- External IP 81.210.109.0, port **9999**, forwarded to 192.168.0.3, port 9
  (Or any other unused port number).

Alternatively, you may be able to log in on the router and sent the the WakeOnLan locally to the right PC, or wake PC A, log in on PC A and send a WoL packet to PC B.

Comment: Thanks thats the logical thing to do, Sadly my router doesnt have the capability to assign incoming data from one port to a different port. It only has to ability to assign incoming data to a specific machine.